# Using a case statement to set the values of declared variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, case

I wanted to know if its possible to set the values of declared variables by using a case statement. 
example:

```
CASE
    WHEN fieldValue ='stringValue1' THEN SET @DeclaredVar1 = 100 
END
```

Comment: Could you include the whole statement or description of what you actually want to do? If that's a select statement for a table with many rows, what should be the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but syntax you've used is incorrect. It should be

```
select @DeclaredVar1 = case 
                         when fieldValue ='stringValue1' then 100 
                         else --another option here-- 
                       end
```

Comment: To the OP: if you want this assignment to have no effect if `fieldValue` is something other than `'stringValue1'`, you can just put `@DeclaredVar1` in for `--another option here--`.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for that. Worked like a charm. I had a feeling that I was almost there. Just couldn't quite get it.